# Disable span when text box is filled with data in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two text boxes with search icon for each in the span, one span icon should disable when one text box is filled with, and the span icon should enable when text box is not filled with data, this should happen vice versa for both the text boxes and spans.

Please help.

Comment: Could you provide the code you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-class for conditional classes. Just create a class which hides the element. Let's suppose `hidden` as the class

`<span ng-class="{'hidden': textEditor.value != ''">Element</span>`

In which textEditor.value is what the textEditor contains